# Unable to find element by XPath if I use following-sibling::

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using the following XPath to locate my element:

```
//tbody/*[contains(.,'abcabc')]/following-sibling::div[1]/a[@class="editbtn"]
```

`//tbody/*[contains(.,'abcabc')]`  fetches me the element so far.

However, when I use `/following-sibling::div[1]/a[@class="editbtn"]` after that, 
or even `/following-sibling::div[1]`,  I get:

> Unable to locate element:

My HTML looks like:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                 <a href="#!/service/1/policies" data-id="1">abcabc</a>
                 <div class="pull-right">
                     <a class="editbtn" title="Edit" href="href1" data-id="1">
                         <i class="icon-edit"/>
                     </a>
                     <a class="deletebtn" title="Delete" href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="1">
                         <i class="icon-trash"/>
                     </a>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look for `//tbody/*[contains(.,'abcabc')]`, you're not selecting what you think you're selecting.

You think you're selecting the `a` element that contains 'abcabc', but you're actually selecting the `tbody` itself because its string value also contains 'abcabc'.   The `tbody` element has no following siblings, so you get nothing.

To select the `div` following the `a` in your example, specify the `//a` rather than using `*` to match any element:

```
//tbody//a[contains(.,'abcabc')]/following-sibling::div[1]
```

That will resolve your `following-sibling` issue and select the `class="pull-right"` `div` that follows the `abcabc` `a` element.